# DevTool Issues can't open

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Probelm[image]

But I  can not open issue? I click on Issues nothing happen.

I click on  "3 points then more tools then issue", but nothing happen.

Have someone a solution please?

Comment: Do you see "Console" or "Issues" in a bar on the bottom? You may need to drag that bar up to make it visible.